# How can we deal with features that are vectors in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

It is often the case that the predictors are variables that take continuous or categorical values in machine learning. However, if the predictors or some of them are vectors, how can we deal with it?

Take interpolation in traditional practices for an example, we use the neighbors to predict the values at the center location $x_0$, denoted briefly here as $f:(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \rightarrow x_0$. We know that the relative location/distance of $x_i,i=1,2,...$ with respect to $x_0$ is important information for an effective interpolation. Therefore, I want to introduce the spatial coordinates into the predictors for modeling, i.e., $f:[(x_1,xcoord_1,ycoord_1),(x_2,xcoord_2,ycoord_2),...,(x_n,xcoord_n,ycoord_n)] \rightarrow x_0$. I did not see this type of models or their invariants in machine learning before. Is there any one who can give some ideas to  deal with the vectors or take advantage of supportive information about each predictor?

Comment: What if you just treated each feature vector as multiple features? You could have one feature vector with three coordinates, another feature vector with three coordinates, and another feature vector with three coordinates, or you could have nine features. Yes, there are relationships between the features, but that’s often the case.

Comment: Transformers, GCNNs and DeepSets will all work with vector features